# Multi-turtlebot3-simulation

Tags: ros, simulation, turtlebot, multiple

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI , all

I am newbie . I want to add a swarm of turtlebot3(burger or waffle) in gazebo to simulate advanced control .

I used the method as the follwing website :

[http://turtlebot3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/simulation.html]

Because  turtlebot3_empty_world.launch file only spawn a turtlebot in gazebo , i tried to modify the launch file :

```
<launch>
<group ns="turtlebot1">
<arg name="model" default="$(env TURTLEBOT3_MODEL)" doc="model type [burger, waffle]"/>
<arg name="x_pos" default="0.0"/>
<arg name="y_pos" default="0.0"/>
<arg name="z_pos" default="0.0"/>


<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py $(find turtlebot3_description)/urdf/turtlebot3_$(arg model).urdf.xacro" />

<node name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-urdf -model turtlebot3_burger -x $(arg x_pos) -y $(arg y_pos) -z $(arg z_pos) -param robot_description" />
</group>

<group ns="turtlebot2">
<arg name="model" default="$(env TURTLEBOT3_MODEL)" doc="model type [burger, waffle]"/>
<arg name="x_pos" default="5.0"/>
<arg name="y_pos" default="5.0"/>
<arg name="z_pos" default="5.0"/>


 <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py $(find turtlebot3_description)/urdf/turtlebot3_$(arg model).urdf.xacro" />

 <node name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-urdf -model turtlebot3_burger -x $(arg x_pos) -y $(arg y_pos) -z $(arg z_pos) -param robot_description" />
  </group>

<include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
<arg name="world_name" value="$(find turtlebot3_gazebo)/models/empty.world"/>
<arg name="paused" value="false"/>
<arg name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
<arg name="gui" value="true"/>
<arg name="headless" value="false"/>
<arg name="debug" value="false"/>
</include>
</launch>
```

It dosent work !!

Dose someone have any idea?

Thanks!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267629/multi-turtlebot3-simulation/) by [pinxian](https://answers.ros.org/users/31206/pinxian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-07-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I modified your launch file a little and it worked for me.

```
<launch>
<group ns="turtlebot1">
<arg name="model" default="$(env TURTLEBOT3_MODEL)" doc="model type [burger, waffle]"/>
<arg name="x_pos" default="0.0"/>
<arg name="y_pos" default="2.0"/>
<arg name="z_pos" default="0.0"/>


<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py $(find turtlebot3_description)/urdf/turtlebot3_$(arg model).urdf.xacro" />

<node name="spawn_urdf_1" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-urdf -model turtlebot3_burger -x $(arg x_pos) -y $(arg y_pos) -z $(arg z_pos) -param robot_description" />
</group>

<group ns="turtlebot2">
<arg name="model" default="$(env TURTLEBOT3_MODEL)" doc="model type [burger, waffle]"/>
<arg name="x_pos_2" default="2.0"/>
<arg name="y_pos_2" default="0.0"/>
<arg name="z_pos_2" default="0.0"/>


 <param name="robot_description_2" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py $(find turtlebot3_description)/urdf/turtlebot3_$(arg model).urdf.xacro" />

 <node name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-urdf -model turtlebot3_burger_2 -x $(arg x_pos_2) -y $(arg y_pos_2) -z $(arg z_pos_2) -param robot_description_2" />
  </group>

<include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
<arg name="world_name" value="$(find turtlebot3_gazebo)/models/empty.world"/>
<arg name="paused" value="false"/>
<arg name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
<arg name="gui" value="true"/>
<arg name="headless" value="false"/>
<arg name="debug" value="false"/>
</include>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [Bane17](https://answers.ros.org/users/34502/bane17/) with karma: 16 on 2018-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-04-05**:
Can you please explain what you modified and why?

**Comment by [Bane17](https://answers.ros.org/users/34502/bane17/) on 2018-04-05**:
Alright, so I'm pretty new at ROS too so I'm not sure I can give you an explanation of why it worked but I modified the <arg name for all of the positions for the second turtlebot as well as the param name="robot_description" and the model name in "<node name="spawn_urdf"...,

**Comment by [Bane17](https://answers.ros.org/users/34502/bane17/) on 2018-04-05**:
Compare your code to what I have, there are only slight differences.